# random number generation between two floats

Tags: objective-c, random, floating-point

I am trying to generate a random number between two floats (the max is increased by its half)

this is what I have so far but it's not working

```
    //range
    NSString *minString = [dict objectForKey:@"min"];
    float minRange = [minString floatValue];
    NSString *maxString = [dict objectForKey:@"max"];
    float maxRange = [maxString floatValue];

    NSLog(@"the ORIGINAL range is %f - %f", minRange, maxRange);

    maxRange = maxRange + (maxRange/2);

    //If you want to get a random integer in the range x to y, you can do that by int randomNumber = (arc4random() % y) + x;

    float randomNumber = (arc4random() % maxRange) + minRange; //ERROR: "Invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'float')

    NSLog(@"the range is %f - %f", minRange, maxRange);
    NSLog(@"the random number is %f", randomNumber);
```

Comment: I had this problem the other day -- seemed to go away when I switched the floats to doubles.  Not sure why.  I'd be interested in seeing an answer to this as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Include:

```
#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX 0x100000000
```

And then try this:

```
double val = ((double)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX) 
   * (maxRange - minRange)
   + minRange;
```

Comment: Thanks! Also making sure to include `#define ARC4RANDOM_MAX 0x100000000`

Comment: This is an awesome solution! Thanks!

Comment: Finally found a solution that works, thanks so much!

Comment: what does 0x100000000 means?

Answer (score 2):

Surely it's:

```
float randomNumber = ((float)arc4random() / ARC4RANDOM_MAX * (maxRange - minRange)) + minRange;
```