# Random number between two decimals in Swift

Tags: ios, random, swift

I'd like to get a random number between two small decimal numbers.

Between maybe 0.8 and 1.3.

```
var duration = CGFloat(arc4random() % 0.8) / 1.3
```

or

```
var duration = CGFloat(arc4random() % 0.5) + 0.8
```

Thanks!

Comment: call that hue twice and store to array if you want to get 2 random numbers.

Comment: This is simple math.  What is the range of the number?

Comment: @HotLicks I don't understand.  Wish I could do this CGFloat(arc4random() % 0.5) + 0.8, but I don't know how to get the right syntax with the decimal numbers.  My range is 0.8 to 1.3.

Comment: @Bejibun I don't want two numbers, I want one number between .8 and 1.3

Comment: @HotLicks please help!  Sounds like you know how to do it.

Comment: What does `%` mean with a floating-point divisor?

Comment: This http://stackoverflow.com/a/6529063/1187415 should be easy to translate to Swift.

Comment: @HotLicks % with non-integral values is described on this page: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/BasicOperators.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swift 5:

Using [random(in:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfloat/2994406-random) which returns a random value within the specified range:

```
var duration = CGFloat.random(in: 0.8 ... 1.3)
```

Per Apple:

> The random() static method chooses a random value from a continuous
>   uniform distribution in range, and then converts that value to the
>   nearest representable value in this type.

See [random(in: using: )](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgfloat/3020516-random) to specify a random generator other than the default.

Answer (score 35):

Here's a generic function I just wrote up quickly to get a random number within a range.

```
func randomBetween(_ firstNum: CGFloat, _ secondNum: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
    return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * abs(firstNum - secondNum) + min(firstNum, secondNum)
}
```

It takes a random number, finds the remainder of that number divided by the difference between the two parameters, then adds by the smaller number. This guarantees the random number to be between the two numbers.

<strike>Disclaimer: I have not tested this out yet.</strike>

**EDIT**: Now this function does what you want.

Comment: I don't think that the remainder operator % accepts a floating point number as the second argument.

Comment: @MartinR that error was just Swift yelling at me for having an Int % CGFloat. Once I casted the Int to CGFloat, it works. And yes, the remainder operator (not modulus) has different behavior in Swift: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/BasicOperators.html

Comment: @MartinR You are correct.  It fails for the same reason as my example

Comment: This isn't as random as I thought it would be (lots of 9's). I will test around in a playground

Comment: If  `firstNum` is always lower than `secondNum`, this should be faster `static func randomBetweenNumbers(lowerNum: CGFloat, higherNum: CGFloat) -> CGFloat{
        return CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UINT32_MAX) * (higherNum - lowerNum) + lowerNum
    }`