# Updating parameter of an SKAction that is repeating forever swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have a function that animates a ball in a game that I am designing right now. However, I want the animation speed to change with the balls actual velocity, which I have achieved but only after each iteration of the animation. That makes it come out a little choppy, I am looking for a more elegant solution that could update the timePerFrame argument mid-action. I originally had it set to repeatforever but realized that timePerFrame wouldn't update once the action had started. Is there a way to make this animation speed change more smoothly?

```
func animBall() {
    //This is the general runAction method to make our ball change color
    var animSpeedNow = self.updateAnimSpeed()
    println(animSpeedNow)
    var animBallAction = SKAction.animateWithTextures(ballColorFrames, timePerFrame: animSpeedNow,resize: false, restore: true)

    self.runAction(animBallAction, completion: {() -> Void in
        self.animBall()

    })
}

func updateAnimSpeed() -> NSTimeInterval{
    // Update the animation speed based on the velocity to syncrhonize animation with ball velocity
    var velocX = self.physicsBody!.velocity.dx
    var velocY = self.physicsBody!.velocity.dy

    if abs(velocX) > 0 || abs(velocY) > 0 {
        var veloc = sqrt(velocX*velocX + velocY*velocY)
        var animSpeedNow: NSTimeInterval = NSTimeInterval(35/veloc)
        let minAS = NSTimeInterval(0.017)
        let maxAS = NSTimeInterval(0.190)

        if animSpeedNow < minAS {
            return maxAS
        }
        else if animSpeedNow > maxAS {
            return minAS
        }
        else {
            return animSpeedNow
        }

    }
    else {
        return NSTimeInterval(0.15)
    }
}
```

If it isn't possible to directly manipulate a parameter of an SKAction that is running forever, I supposed I

Comment: Don't try to slow down the animation itself, instead, control the speed with your animation implementation.

Comment: As an addition to Wraithseeker's answer, take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/q/30853360/3402095 Maybe you find something useful from those answers.

Comment: Kametrixom: could you be more specific? Is there a different way to animate that would be useful for what I am trying to do?

Whirlwind: What I did in my code is essentially the same as the accepted answer on that page, which is to use a recursive solution (self.animball)

Answer (score 1):

In your case, a simpler way would be to remove the old animation action and replace it with a new one.