# Modify SKActions during the game

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I am developing a game where all the enemies are SKNodes in their own classes. Within my SKScene I am spawning the mobs via allocing them and calling a specific method for spawning.

However, when they are spawned each mob are defined with a set of actions they run during their lifetime. One example are for one specific mob is:

```
    SKAction *moveLeft = [SKAction moveToX:0 - (fragment.size.width/2) + (width / 2) duration:1.0];
    SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction moveToX:(fragment.size.width / 2) - (width / 2) duration:1.0];

    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveLeft, moveRight]];
    SKAction *bounceOnWalls = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];

    [enemy runAction:bounceOnWalls];
```

So, back to my question. How can I modify a specific SKAction after its been created? I would like to change lets say the speed of `moveLeft` for all enemies that have this SKAction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run action with key :

```
SKAction *moveLeft = [SKAction moveToX:0 - (fragment.size.width/2) + (width / 2) duration:1.0];
    SKAction *moveRight = [SKAction moveToX:(fragment.size.width / 2) - (width / 2) duration:1.0];

    SKAction *sequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveLeft, moveRight]];
    SKAction *bounceOnWalls = [SKAction repeatActionForever:sequence];

    [enemy runAction:bounceOnWalls withKey:@"moving"]; //Run action with key
```

And when you need to change the speed on all nodes which running that action, you can use enumerateChildNodesWithName method. Like this:

```
[parentNode enumerateChildNodesWithName:name usingBlock:^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop){

        if([node actionForKey:@"moving"]){


            SKAction* action = [node actionForKey:@"moving"];

           action.speed = 1.5f;

        }

    }];
```

You could probably change dynamically duration of actions and affect in that way on speed of moving nodes, but I think that changing speed of an action directly is better choice. Take a look at both answers in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30853360/3402095) on how you can change duration parameter dynamically.